# Can I check for events with SDL without using an embedded while_loop?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, glfw, game-loop

I originally wrote my game using glfw. However due to it lack of android portability I have to replace all of my glfw code with SDL, since SDL is more portable.

My original game loop using the glfw frame work was very striaghtforward. Here it is:

```
// game loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    //if-else statements that create  
    //the games state machine
    //player input is received here
    //rendering done here
}
```

Ok. There are probably better ways of writing this game loop, but the point is the code worked for the game prototype.

However now that I'm switching to SDL I have encountered a problem. It seems that SDL_Event  has to be placed into a while loop to constantly check for events. And THIS while_loop is within another while_loop. So my code looks like this:

```
while(!Quit) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        //if-else statements that create  
        //the games state machine
        //player input is received here
        //rendering done here
    }
}
```

However this while_loop within a while_loop has completely messed up the games rendering! I'm now getting flickering! Is there any other way to express this code in just a single while_loop as I did earlier with glfw. Or is there any way to check for events without using an embedded while_loop

Comment: Shouldn't the `SDL_PollEvent()` loop just deal with events?  Your rendering code and such should be outside that, in your outer loop... as is, you only render, etc. when you process an event...

Answer (score 5):

Rendering and calculations should not be done inside the event-polling loop, do it outside.

This is how I currently do it in SDL2 for a game I wrote in [c](/questions/tagged/c):

```
while (!quit) {
    start_frame_ms = SDL_GetTicks();

    /* Event polling */
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        joystick_event(&event);
        keyboard_event(&event);
    }

    /* Calculations */
    players_move();
    enemies_move();

    /* Rendering */
    draw_sprites();

    /* Lock FPS to 60 */
    end_frame_ms = start_frame_ms - SDL_GetTicks();
    if (end_frame_ms < FPMS) {
        SDL_Delay(FPMS - end_frame_ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to have a separate thread for rendering, but that is a different story.

Comment: @Matso Wouldn't that result in coordinates from the calculations functions not be in sync with the sprites being drawn?

Comment: If no sync methods were applied, of course. I'm just saying that in big engines there usually are separate threads for many different things (rendering, audio, input etc.).

Comment: @Matso not sure if it is portable. I've seen deadlocked SDL_WaitEvent in that setup.